# use string as columns definition for DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(),columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to use a string as column names for pandas DataFrame.

The problem arised is that pandas DataFrame interpret the string var as single column instead of multiple ones. An thus the error:

ValueError: 1 columns passed, passed data had 11 columns

The first part of my code is intended to get the column names from the Mysql database I am about to query:

```
cursor1.execute ("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) AS cols FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'or_red' AND TABLE_NAME = 'nomen_prefix'")
for colsTableMysql in cursor1.fetchall() :
    colsTable = colsTableMysql[0]

colsTable="'"+colsTable.replace(",", "','")+"'"
```

The second part uses the created variable "colsTable" :

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM or_red.nomen_prefix WHERE C_emp IN ("+emplazamientos+")")
    tabla = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(),columns=[colsTable])
    #tabla = exec("pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(),columns=["+colsTable+"])")
    #tabla = pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall())
```

I have tried ather aproaches like the use of exec(). In that case, there is no error but there is no response with information either, and the result of print(tabla) is None.

¿Is there any direct way of passing the columns dynamically as string to a python pandas DataFrame?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer my question since I've already found the way.

The first part of my code is intended to get the column names from the Mysql database table I am about to query:

```
cursor1.execute ("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) AS cols FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'or_red' AND TABLE_NAME = 'nomen_prefix'")
for colsTableMysql in cursor1.fetchall() :
    colsTable = colsTableMysql[0]

colsTable="'"+colsTable.replace(",", "','")+"'"
```

The second part uses the created variable "colsTable" as input in the statement to define the columns.

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM or_red.nomen_prefix WHERE C_emp IN ("+emplazamientos+")")
    
    tabla = eval("pd.DataFrame(cursor.fetchall(),columns=["+colsTable+"])")
```

Using eval the string is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression.